# Incorrect solution in limits

Tags: limits

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n^4}{+3^{\frac{2}{2+n}}}\right)^{n}
$$

So i re-write it like:
$\lim_{n\to \infty}e^{n\ln{\frac{1}{n^4}\ln3^{\frac{2}{2+n}}}}$ $=$  $e^{\frac{2n}{2+n}\ln{\frac{1}{n^4}\ln3}}=e^{{2}\ln{\frac{1}{n^4}\ln3}}$

So here, $\ln{\frac{1}{n^4}}$ give  us minus infinity, but i think that somewhere i lost a way, so i need some hints

Comment: It looks like you incorrectly assumed the log of a sum is the product of the logs.

Comment: @GEdgar, i find it thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $n=\frac{1}{y}$ .The limit reduces to

$L=\lim_{y\to 0}\left(y^4+3^{\frac{2y}{2y+1}}\right)^{\frac{1}{y}}$

Take log on both sides

$\log_{e}L=\lim_{y\to 0} \log_{e}\left(y^4+3^{\frac{2y}{2y+1}}\right)^{\frac{1}{y}}$

$\log_{e}L=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1}{y} \log_{e}\left(y^4+3^{\frac{2y}{2y+1}}\right)$

$\log_{e}L=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{ \log_{e}\left(1+y^4+3^{\frac{2y}{2y+1}}-1\right)}{y^4+3^{\frac{2y}{2y+1}}-1}\frac{y^4+3^{\frac{2y}{2y+1}}-1}{y}$

$\log_{e}L=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{ \log_{e}\left(1+y^4+3^{\frac{2y}{2y+1}}-1\right)}{y^4+3^{\frac{2y}{2y+1}}-1}\left(y^3+\frac{3^{\frac{2y}{2y+1}}-1}{\frac{2y}{2y+1}}\frac{2}{2y+1}\right)=1\left(2\log_{e}3\right)=\log_{e}9$

As $y\to 0$ it is obvious that $y^4+3^{\frac{2y}{2y+1}}-1\to 0$.

So here  the standard result $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log_{e}(1+x)}{x}=1$ has been used.

Also as $y\to 0$ it is obvious that $\frac{2y}{2y+1}\to 0$

so the standard limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\log_{e}a$ can be used.

Hence,$L=9$

Comment: Can u show more information how did u get 2*ln3

Comment: I have edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \;\infty } \left( {1 + \frac{a}
{n}} \right)^{\,n}  = e^{\,a} \quad \quad \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \;\infty } \left( {1 + \frac{{f(n)}}
{n}} \right)^{\,n}  \ne \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \;\infty } e^{\,f(n)} 
$$
that's the fault in your derivation. Consider instead that we have:
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \;\infty } \left( {1 + \frac{a}
{{\left( {n + \alpha } \right)}} + \frac{b}
{{\left( {n + \beta } \right)^{\,2} }} +  \cdots } \right)^{\,n + \gamma }  = e^{\,a} 
$$

Therefore we shall try and expand $3^{2/(2+n)}$ in powers of the exponent, i.e. Taylor of $3^x \quad | \, x=2/(2+n) \approx 0$
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \;\infty } \left( {\frac{1}
{{n^{\,4} }} + 3^{\,\frac{2}
{{2 + n}}} } \right)^{\,n}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \;\infty } \left( {e^{\frac{{2\ln 3}}
{{2 + n}}}  + \frac{1}
{{n^{\,4} }}} \right)^{\,n}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \;\infty } \left( {1 + \frac{{2\ln 3}}
{{2 + n}} + \frac{{\left( {2\ln 3} \right)^2 }}
{2}\frac{1}
{{\left( {2 + n} \right)^2 }} +  \cdots  + \frac{1}
{{n^{\,4} }}} \right)^{\,n}  =  \hfill \\
   = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\; \to \;\infty } \left( {1 + \frac{{2\ln 3}}
{{2 + n}}} \right)^{\,n}  = e^{2\ln 3}  = 9 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

Comment: U have used Taylor expansion? I didnt understand why u plus and minus 2 in last 1/(2+n-2) is it should be just look like last term , and about that -2 in power u canceled by adding +2 to the n in the n→inf? Is it ok? Sorr if the question kind of stupid

Comment: @МузаффарШакаров Well, I tried and make more readable my answer.  It should solve now your questions, if not do not hesitate to ask again.

Answer (score 1):

We can see that it is " tending to one" raised to the power "tending to infinity" then we can use this as a shortcut[image]

Then use L'Hospital rule to simplify